# When use the Multi-Page App on vite, will miss the js file when building

Tags: reactjs, nested, vite

I tried using vite's [multi-app](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app) feature to integrate a project made of pure `html/css/js` into `vite`. However, when it was built, the js file path that was included in index.html was not included in the build, resulting in `404` error.

[tag:NOTE: The images folder and fonts and css are well included and built.]

### Reproduction

```bash
yarn create vite example-web --template react-swc-ts
```

- tree

```
├── package.json
├── vite.config.js
├── index.html
├── main.js
└── nested
    ├── index.html
    └── js
        └── aaa.js
        └── ddd.js
    └── css
    └── images
    └── fonts
```

nested/index.html

```html
....
<body>
<script src="js/aaa.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/ddd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

- vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'
import { resolve,extname } from 'path'
import { globSync } from 'glob'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        ...Object.fromEntries(globSync('nested/**/*.html').map(file => [file.slice(0, file.length - (extname(file).length +6)),file])),
      }
    },
  },

})
```

I thought it would be built with the js file included.